# Error when trying retrieve record id from external object detail page on button click

Tags: externalobjects

I have a custom button on a external object detail page which executes a java script.I am trying to fetch the id of the record var id = '{!ExternalObject__x.Id}' and when i click on save I received the below error

> Error: Field ExternalObject__x.Id does not exist. Check spelling.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: If you're actually merging in `ExternalObject_x` the problem may be a single underscore where it should be double. As the error suggests, double check your spelling.

Comment: It has a underscore in the javascript.That was a typo error

Comment: I think it should be like this: var id = "{!ExternalObject__x.Id}".. Use double quotes